# How to find holes in a Pandas time index

Tags: python, pandas

I am interesting in knowing if a time index contains holes. Say I have the following Series

```
ss = pd.Series( nr.randn(3), index=[ '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03' ] )
ss.index = pd.to_datetime( ss.index )
ss
```

Output

```
2014-01-01    0.976455
2014-01-02   -0.610322
2014-01-03   -0.631592
dtype: float64
```

I thought I could do what I would do with lists (`l[1:]-l[:-1]`)

```
ss.index[1:] - ss.index[:-1]
```

But here is the output, which I don't understand

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-01-03]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I ended up doing this (which is kinda ugly)

```
tmp = pd.Series( ss.index[1:] ) - pd.Series( ss.index[:-1] )
(tmp[0] == tmp ).all()
```

So I have 2 questions:

- What is `ss.index[1:] - ss.index[:-1]` doing?
- Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly different method. A frequency will be returned if it can (e.g. its daily if the values are daily spaced with no holes). `None` otherwise.

```
In [14]: pd.infer_freq(Series(np.random.randn(3),index=['20140101','20140102','20140103']).index)
Out[14]: 'D'

In [15]: pd.infer_freq(Series(np.random.randn(3),index=['20140101','20140102','20140104']).index)

In [31]: pd.infer_freq(Series(np.random.randn(3),index=['20140101','20140201','20140301']).index)
Out[31]: 'MS'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `numpy.diff()`:

```
np.diff(np.array(ss.index))
```

There is probably some slightly slicker way to do this, but the above works.  It gives you:

```
array([86400000000000, 86400000000000], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
tDelta = ss.index.date[1:]-ss.index.date[:-1]
secondBetweenEachEntries = [t.total_seconds() for t in tDelta]
```

That gives

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as nr
ss = pd.Series( nr.randn(3), index=[ '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03' ] )
ss.index = pd.to_datetime( ss.index )
tDelta = ss.index.date[1:]-ss.index.date[:-1]
```